# How to do an arithmetic operation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two numbers in a table corresponding to different years (as shown below).

How do I write a `SELECT` query to calculate the difference in value between 2014 and 2013.

```
Table 1 sample information:

year           value
--------------------
2013            100
2014            150
```

Comment: you want `2013-100=1913`, or `150-100=50`?

Comment: a self join with 2 aliases

Comment: @MarcB I need to do 150-100

Comment: If you know which numbers you want to subtract, then what's the point? Sorry I don't get it.

Comment: @itoctopus Is ok show a simple sample of a more complex problem. I think the sample provide enough into to show where OP need help.

Comment: @GustavoMoreno IMHO, getting a good understanding of a solution along the lines of `tbl1.yr = (tbl2.yr + 1)` is quite useful.  I've run across stored procs with hardcoded dates so spare yourself (and maybe others) from the pain.

Comment: You shouldnt change that question so dramatic. That will make all the answer already made useless. Please create a new question and leave this one as is for other to check.  Also dont use picture to show data. Try http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html is easy copy paste from text than one image

Comment: If that is ok with you i will rollback to the original question text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont like it too much because is very specific. But this is a way without `join` using conditional `SUM`

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
              WHEN year = 2014 THEN value
              ELSE -value
           END) as total
FROM Table1
```

Comment: now that qualifies as a [Rube Goldberg Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) :)

Comment: @Drew I know :P,  But the coolest part is looks more efficient as other answers isnt?

Comment: I call this the WWGD aproach, (What Will Gordon Do).

Comment: problem is the rowcount on a probable schema, [pastie](http://pastie.org/10484230)

Comment: What if there are more years/values?

Comment: Hola @GustavoMoreno I only answer the question you made. For that small case I found a cleaver solution. But other answers here use some imagination and previous knoledge on what you may need. if lot of values of 2013/2014 still will work. But for diffent year doesnt. Anyway if you need different years you also should include what is your desire output. Please read this for ideas on how make a better question  [**Need an Answer? Actually, No ... You Need a Question**](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx)

Comment: My advice is if you need more specific solution work a ltile more in preparing your question. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: well I gave it an upvote because it is imaginative, and gave a pastie above with a warning (if one can read `explain` output which is cryptic) with a proposed schema. But @JuanCarlosOropeza is right, the question needs improvement. Some peeps will come along and learn something from his `case/when`. All positive stuff for newbies.

Comment: OK used this reasoning (the problem is more complex than the example) and it worked great. It is an efficient and elegant solution.

Comment: Hey @GustavoMoreno dont play with my feelings :P. I was already celebrating my accept answer. Why you change your mind? At least leave an upvote

Comment: I disagree that it takes "imagination" to suppose that the table might contain more than two rows of data, that maybe/probably the OP used an intentionally simplified the dataset to focus on the algorithm. I mean, if there were really only two values, then use a calculator.

Comment: @LeeJenkins My query work with more than two values  but only if years  are `(2013,2014)`  but indeed can be multiple years but that is only a guess. And in that case what format would you put those?. For example Michael answer is great but he assume lot of thing. I just try to answer the question OP ask.  And I think Is better encourage OP to write a clear question. And as you can see the original question has change a lot from original post.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to realize you need to join the table to itself so that you're operating on rows that can tell you something about two different years. For example:

```
SELECT t1.value-t2.value as difference
FROM yourtable AS t1
INNER JOIN yourtable AS t2 
ON(t1.year=2013 AND t2.year=2014)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT (a.value-b.value) as difference from table as a 
INNER JOIN table as b
on a.year=2014 and b.year =2015
```

Comment: please use explicit joins in your joins :)

Comment: changed, my bad, did it in a hurry

Comment: @Drew I have this link to teach why is better explicit joins. Aaron Bertrand did some [**writting**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it

Comment: @javaguest Use `ctrl-k` to format your text to code format

Comment: lol for copying my answer from yours I put the years wrong. The years are `2013 and 2014`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a SQL server handy to try this, but I would use sub-queries, like this::

```
SELECT (SELECT value FROM your_table WHERE year = 2014) -
       (SELECT value FROM your_table WHERE year = 2013) AS Area
```

Comment: What I've done, based on your suggestion, is this:

    SELECT
        (SELECT land_value/surface 
     FROM Sample
     WHERE id_neighborhood = 22 AND surface IS NOT NULL AND year = 2014) - 
        (SELECT land_value/surface 
     FROM Sample
     WHERE id_neighborhood = 22 AND surface IS NOT NULL AND year = 2013);

And as a result, I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XM1TT.png) in MySQL Workbench (sorry, different field names).

It is the correct result but it has the SQL query attached and it never happened to me before, so I don't understand why.

Comment: Yes, SQL server reports the column name(s) in the output. In this case, the sub-queries are the column name. You can alias the name using AS. I will edit the answer to demonstrate.

Comment: You're right. My bad, I forgot to alias the column name.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should learn about relational databases is that any record in a table is *semantically equivalent* to the others. I mean: You could have two records in your table (2013 and 2014)... or you could have a hundred of them. So, you should think your query in terms of a table with *an indeterminate number* of records.

For example: A query that computes the difference between any record and the previous one:

Step by step:

A list of all records:

```
SELECT year, value FROM table
```

A join between records by year:

```
SELECT a.year, a.value, b.year, b.value 
FROM table AS a INNER JOIN table AS b ON a.year=b.year
```

A join between records by previous year:

```
SELECT a.year, a.value, b.year, b.value 
FROM table AS a INNER JOIN table AS b ON a.year=1+b.year
```

At last, the difference between a year and the previous:

```
SELECT a.year, a.value, b.year, b.value, a.value-b.value
FROM table AS a INNER JOIN table AS b ON a.year=1+b.year
```

Answer (score 1):

A general solution. Assume table like this one (named `year_val` as an example):

```
mysql> select * from year_val;
+------+------+
| year | val  |
+------+------+
| 2015 |  100 |
| 2014 |  120 |
| 2013 |  500 |
| 2012 |  400 |
+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT yv1.year AS current_year
    ,yv2.year AS last_year
    ,yv1.val AS current_val
    ,yv2.val AS last_val
    ,yv2.val - yv1.val AS difference
FROM year_val yv1
INNER JOIN year_val yv2 
        ON yv1.year = yv2.year + 1;
```

**OUTPUT**.

```
+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+------------+
| current_year | last_year | current_val | last_val | difference |
+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+------------+
|         2015 |      2014 |         100 |      120 |         20 |
|         2014 |      2013 |         120 |      500 |        380 |
|         2013 |      2012 |         500 |      400 |       -100 |
+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: That works if it is a year and it is a number. What if, for example, they are city names and populations, and you want to calculate the difference of populations between specific two cities?

Comment: @GustavoMoreno As for other data types, it's just a matter of how you'd like to sort and what does a 'previous' city mean anyway? Glad my answer works for you. Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

based on Juan's answer, here is a more 'enterprise' way of solving this problem

```
SELECT a.value - b.value as difference from (select year, value from table = 2014) as a 
INNER JOIN (select year, value from table where year = 2015) as b
on a.year = 2015 and b.year = 2014 
WHERE a.year = 2015 and b.year = 2014
```